# Converting below txt table to csv table format

Tags: shell-script

I have a Table in unix with below format and covert as output.

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
|           col_name       |        type             |   
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
| Name                     |    String               |
| Date                     | Fri 29 13:17:2020       |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
```

Output:

```
"col_name","type"
"Name","String"
"Date","Fri 29 13:17:2020"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? Some database engines knows how to export CSV directly from a query.  Converting the data that you show _reliably_ to CSV is not possible as whitespace characters have been inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
input ()
{
  cat <<EOF
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
|           col_name       |        type             |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
| Name                     |    String               |
| Date                     | Fri 29 13:17:2020       |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
EOF
}

input |
  tr -d '|+-' |                # remove decoration
  grep -v ^$ |                 # remove empty lines
  while read first rest; do    # read first token and rest of the line
    printf '"%s","%s"\n' \
           "$first" "$rest"    # format as required
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

The source looks like a response to dbase client in console. But the end of lines and lot of spaces are missing, probably lost by openig a unix text with Notepad. With the original format (unproporcional font) the source may form a nice table.

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+ 
| col_name                 | type                    |
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+ 
| Name                     | String                  | 
| Date                     | Fri 29 13:17:2020       | 
+--------------------------+-------------------------+-+
```

Look at the text file in hex editor, to see what does it realy content. Than you can write a command to convert it to requested form. (With the format it could not be written as a comment, what this realy is)

Comment: I agree with your wish to be able to format multi-line comments.

Comment: Sorry,  Mr. Steeldriver did the job - he correctly edited the original text, and Mr. Kusalananda put relevant comment. My answer should be deletet as redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` program should do the job, provided that none of the field values can contain quotes (the result would be a non-comforming CSV):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="," '/^\+/{next} {for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {gsub(/^ *| *$/,"",$i); printf("\"%s\"%s",$i,i<(NF-1)?OFS:ORS)}}' input.txt
```

This will

- treat `|` as field separator
- ignore any lines starting with `+`
- ignore the first and last "field" (which are empty as they are the "content" before the first and after the last `|`) of those lines that don't start with `+`, and print the remaining fields, whitespace-trimmed and enclosed in double quotes, with `,` as field separator.

It is assumed that any leading and trailing whitespace inside the cells is purely decoration, and that the input file doesn't contain empty lines.